# From where to create PayPal Developer/Sandbox account

Tags: paypal

I have worked with PayPal earlier and had test accounts. 
However, I now want to create a NEW TEST account and work with new only.

PayPal is giving link on developer pages to create an account but it navigates to professional paypal user account create page and asks real creditcard/post code etc detail.

Please let me know if this is the only way to create an account with paypal or there's another page for developers to create test accounts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you need to create account on => https://www.paypal.com/webapps/merchantboarding/webflow/unifiedflow?&returnUrl=//developer.paypal.com/developer&countryCode=US&productIntentID=developer_standard&signupType=CREATE_NEW_ACCOUNT&displayMode=regular

After then you would be able to login with same credentials on => https://developer.paypal.com/

Hope it helps someone looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create test account by going to [Paypal Developer Site](https://developer.paypal.com/) then go to Applications -> Sand Box Accounts -> Create Account

Comment: thanks for reply but if you re-read my question, the exact text _Create Account_ is found nowhere, plus the only link given to create account is of live site. (I have been redirected to [link](https://www.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/home) upon clicking the link and SignUp here asks for real credit/debit phone details) - this is not something like developer.paypal.com/sandbox/Signup link we expect.